# Black screen with blinking cursor after install gnome on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, video, screen, gdm

I try to connect with UltraVNC to my Ubuntu 22.04 GNOME Desktop envirement.
I can login with SSH successfully to my server 45.13.59.126.
I have installed Gnome by commands:

```
 sudo apt install gnome-session gdm3
 sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
 sudo apt install tasksel
 sudo tasksel
```

But when I connect with `ultravnc` I get BLACK SCREEN with underscore

It seems that video drivers aren't installed correctly.

```
Aug 26 07:01:21 vmi995554 gdm3: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Aug 26 07:01:21 vmi995554 gdm-launch-environment]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 26 07:01:21 vmi995554 gdm3: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Aug 26 07:01:21 vmi995554 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[955]: #011(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
Aug 26 07:01:21 vmi995554 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[955]: (EE) FBDEV(0): mode initialization failed
Aug 26 07:01:21 vmi995554 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[955]: Fatal server error:
Aug 26 07:01:21 vmi995554 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[955]: (EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
Aug 26 07:01:21 vmi995554 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[955]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
Host: KVM/QEMU (Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996) pc-i440fx-5.2)

Comment: Hi, I have remove nomodeset from boot options. Now it works!